# Suspicious connections - Having issues with the GUI under Debian by connection to a public remote node - PC hangs

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, security, linux, nodes

Having a Windows client with local node - works perfect.

When trying to connect with the Debian client to a remote node (eu.node.moneroworld.com at port 18089) the pc hangs immediately and cinnamon isn't reacting anymore and the cpu fan goes to full speed.

Checked the network connections for seconds in another terminal and found these suspicous ones: 
https://s33.postimg.cc/twpk1iw67/IMG1.jpg
This happened three times. Every time the same addresses. 
Googled it, but couldn't find anything monero related - only old spam mail addresses.

I directly cut the network connection physically and shutdown the pc via terminal.

Any suggestions? And just for your info, if you find out that your Debian pc hangs with the gui/monerod client.

I am going to use a local node in Debian too, but wanted to checkout how I can get a fast look into my wallet, when I am on a new PC/VM/in hurry.

Answer (score 1):

*node.moneroworld.com* (in your case, the *eu* regional) connect to random nodes registered by gentle users on monerowold.com.
Looking at your capture, it seems the node you are forwarded to is based in Russia (which could be correct for *eu* location if west Russia).
Is it a legitimate node with a small bandwidth, or a scamy node you should not trust, no one could say.
Nevertheless, i do not know any security flaws in daemon RPC which could compromise your wallet using it.
You are just requesting block headers, parse them, and then requests full transactions when your wallet find your addresses while parsing the *tx_keys* in headers.

My guess is your computer freeze because the node is slow and the bandwidth tiny. If you look at a top while syncing, you should see if your cpu is stuck with I/O waits.

But, as you have a full node on your windows computer, why don't you connect your debian wallet to this windows node? Aren't they available at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned I am looking for a quick trustful handle to have access to the wallet. How is it possible to use the wallets within seconds, other than use a remote node? The Debian pc is a notebook, which goes only some days online and is for travelling. When I always have to update the blockchain, it will take half an hour to hours to sync... Any other tipps to for the quick & safest way to use the wallet (without online-wallets)?

Comment: Then you should make your node (windows device) available on internet (secured with a login password and a tuned RPC port) and connect to your own node. It's the only node that you should fully trust.